# Rdd get combinations of items

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to Spark and Scala.
I have a RDD that looks like:

```
I1
I2
I3
I4
```

I need to genereate all the combinations of this rdd by parameter

```
1 => I1 I2 I3 I4

2 => (I1, I2), (I1, I3)...

3 => (I1,I2,I3)...
```

The results must not contain repeating items like `(I2,I3,I2)`

The order does not matter `(I1, I2)` is the same as `(I2, I1)`. How do i do that?

I have tried using built in functions such as cartesin but that didnt help...

i have no idea what to do

Comment: Homework?? Please explain what you have tried.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is that SO is not the place to go if you just want the solution to a problem - nobody here is interested in doing your work for you. However, if you have a genuine interest in learning how to solve a problem, you will already have tried to solve the problem yourself and I'm simply asking that you describe to us what sort of attempts you have made and why that didn't work. Preferably you can show us some code so we can experiment with that ourselves.